# Sampling rate in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, sampling

Can I know what is the sampling rate of ifft() command which is a build in function in matlab?
I am dealing with a proposed method which overcome limitation of ifft, so i want to know the default sampling rate of ifft() build in function in matlab.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Have you read the documentation of the `ifft()` function, at the bottom there are the equations explaining everything? Please read [ask]

Comment: @Irreducible the question explained everything